# Iptables, subnet rule overwriting ip rule

Tags: linux, iptables

I want to `DROP` all packet that come from the subnet `192.168.112.0/24` with destination `192.168.112.0/24` but I want to allow only a specific destination to be accessible (`192.168.112.253`).

I am using the following rules, the first (`DROP`) rule is working as expected dropping all packets but the second (`ACCEPT`) rule is not allowing packets for the specific destination to pass.

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.112.0/24 -d 192.168.112.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.112.0/24 -d 192.168.112.253 -j ACCEPT
```

[image]

Is there any reason why the first rule (`ACCEPT`) is being ignored ?

Comment: This exact configuration works for me.

Comment: Are the hosts in the subnet configured to route traffics for their "neighbors" to the gateway host though? Or do they have a *direct* route for `192.168.112.0/24` (and L2 client isolation or whatever is in effect)?

Comment: Hi @TomYan , I am not quite clear with the question. What do you mean by "neighbors" ?

The subnet traffic is routed through the host, and then the host routes all outgoing traffic. Currently only this subnet has been configured. Hope this helps.

Comment: So I assume an empty FORWARD chain (with policy being ACCEPT) does not make a difference? And have you enabled (i.e., sysctl) IP forwarding on this host?

Comment: I tired a FORWARD chain with only the above rules and nothing changed, yes sysctl IP v4 forwarding is active.

Comment: For the record, by neighhors I mean hosts with an IP within the subnet block. Ethernet hosts within the same IP subnet don't usually communicate with each other via their default gateway since they don't have to. And you sort of need a "special" configuration if you want them to. Or is this a VPN?

Comment: This is a VPN, more specific this is WireGuard.

Comment: Actually, I think you need an ACCEPT rule for the reply traffics (253 to 0/24), or the "stateful complementary rule", before the DROP rule.

Comment: @TomYan something like: `iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.112.253 -d 192.168.112.0/24 -j ACCEPT` ?

Comment: Even this is not working `iptables -I FORWARD --src 192.168.112.0/24 ! --dst 192.168.112.253 --jump DROP` but these works `iptables -I FORWARD --src 192.168.112.0/24 --dst 192.168.112.253 --jump DROP`
`iptables -I FORWARD --src 192.168.112.0/24 --dst 192.168.112.0/24 --jump ACCEPT`

Comment: I mean you need three rules. The DROP rule (for 0/24 0/24) should be the last one (so should be `-I` first). Before that (so `-I` later) you should have two ACCEPT rules, with 0/24 and 253 and as src/dst and dst/src respectively. The order of the two rules don't matter.

Comment: @TomYan you are correct, after some trial and error I was able to make this work with the same method you suggested. Do you want to post an answer in this thread?

Comment: Yeah I'll post an answer with some explanation in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing you missed is that you also need an `ACCEPT` rule for replies from `192.168.112.253` to `192.168.112.0/24` to be allowed:

```
-I FORWARD -s 192.168.112.253 -d 192.168.112.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

Both `ACCEPT` rules need to be placed before (i.e., `-I` later than) the `DROP` rule, since `192.168.112.0/24` covers `192.168.112.253`, which means the traffics that you wished to be "whitelisted" will be covered by it. Therefore, if it is matched against first, the `ACCEPT` rules will not have any effect.

The order among the two `ACCEPT` rules themselves does not matter though, since they don't "overlap" with each other.

There are two caveats with the approach adopted here by the way. First, as you can see, you'll need two (`ACCEPT`) rules for each "pair" of traffics. Second, it allows `192.168.112.253` to initiate connections to the `192.168.112.0/24`. (With that said, you may consider neither of them an actual problem.)

Often we simply have the following "stateful" rule that allows all replying traffics:

```
-I FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

(To be precise, traffics of both directions will have the state of `ESTABLISHED` except the very first one that initiates the connection. `RELATED` is used for certain recognized replying traffics in which the port number pair is not just swapped but different from the original traffic. The `,` means "inclusive or", even though a traffic won't be in both states at a time. Consider the info within the parentheses "AFAIK" though.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce your problem.

I have a host at `172.17.0.2/16`. Initially, it can reach any host on the `192.168.1.0/24` network:

```
/ # ping -c1 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: seq=0 ttl=63 time=0.350 ms

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.350/0.350/0.350 ms
/ # ping -c1 192.168.1.6
PING 192.168.1.6 (192.168.1.6): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.6: seq=0 ttl=63 time=6.690 ms

--- 192.168.1.6 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 6.690/6.690/6.690 ms
```

If on the intervening router I add this rule:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 172.17.0.0/16 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j DROP
```

Then the host is no longer able to reach any host on the `192.168.1.0/24` network:

```
/ # ping -c1 192.118.1.1
PING 192.118.1.1 (192.118.1.1): 51 data bytes

--- 192.118.1.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

But if I add the appropriate `ACCEPT` rule:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 172.17.0.0/16 -d 192.168.1.1 -j ACCEPT
```

Then I have restored connectivity to `192.168.1.1`:

```
/ # ping -c1 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: seq=0 ttl=63 time=0.484 ms

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.484/0.484/0.484 ms
```

While connections to other hosts on the `192.168.1.0/24` network continue to be blocked:

```
/ # ping -c1 192.168.1.6
PING 192.168.1.6 (192.168.1.6): 56 data bytes

--- 192.168.1.6 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

---

After adding both of those rules, the `FORWARD` chain looks like:

```
# iptables -S FORWARD
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 172.17.0.0/16 -d 192.168.1.1/32 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 172.17.0.0/16 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j DROP
```

Comment: This is very strange, I ran a new test where I `DROP` all packets that are coming from the subnet to my specific destination and then I added a new rule which allows the packets to go through.


`iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.112.0/24 -d 192.168.112.253 -j DROP`
`iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.112.0/24 -d 192.168.112.253 -j ACCEPT`

In this scenario the packets are passing and I can ping `192.168.112.253` but if I change the rule to block the subnet it fails.

Comment: For the record, in your testing case, traffics from `192.168.1.1` / `192.168.1.0/24` to `172.17.0.0/16` is allowed because they are not covered by the (only) `DROP` rule, but in the OP's case, the story is different.